# Class vs unique_ptr<MyClass> causes Vulkan error

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, vulkan

I have been developing a library of C++ classes for Vulkan. I have run across a problem with using class vs `unique_ptr` to the same class. I have been doing this work using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

I will begin with code from a couple of classes and then show how they are used to illustrate the problem. First is the `Queue` class:

```
class Queue
{
public:
    inline Queue() : Queue(VK_NULL_HANDLE) {}
    inline explicit Queue(const VkQueue queue) : m_queue(queue) {}
    inline Queue(const Queue& queue) = default;
    inline Queue& operator=(const Queue& queue) = default;
    inline Queue(Queue&&) = default;
    inline Queue& operator=(Queue&&) = default;
    inline ~Queue() = default;
    inline VkQueue getHandle() const noexcept { return m_queue; }

private:
    VkQueue m_queue;
};
```

and now code from my `LogicalDevice` class that returns either a `Queue` or a `unique_ptr<Queue>`;

```
__declspec(dllexport) Queue LogicalDevice::getQueue(
    const uint32_t queueFamilyIndex,
    const uint32_t queueIndex) {
    VkQueue queue = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    vkGetDeviceQueue(m_device, queueFamilyIndex, queueIndex, &queue);
    Queue q(queue);
    return q;
}

__declspec(dllexport) std::unique_ptr<Queue> LogicalDevice::getQueuePtr(
    const uint32_t queueFamilyIndex,
    const uint32_t queueIndex) {
    VkQueue queue = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    vkGetDeviceQueue(m_device, queueFamilyIndex, queueIndex, &queue);
    auto q = std::make_unique<Queue>(queue);
    return q;
}
```

For my window, I have declared the following class variables:

```
Queue m_graphicsQ;
std::unique_ptr<Queue> m_graphicsQueue;
```

In the initialization code for the window I have:

```
m_graphicsQ = m_logicalDevice->getQueue(indices.graphicsFamily, 0);
```

and in the drawing code:

```
VkQueue queue = m_graphicsQ.getHandle();
result = vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
```

This code works (result is `VK_SUCCESS`). Now if I try to use `unique_ptr` to `Queue` instead:

```
m_graphicsQueue = m_logicalDevice->getQueuePtr(indices.graphicsFamily, 0);
```

and

```
VkQueue queue2 = m_graphicsQueue->getHandle();
result = vkQueueSubmit(queue2, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
```

result is `VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST`.

In attempting to debug this, I used the following code:

```
m_graphicsQ = m_logicalDevice->getQueue(indices.graphicsFamily, 0);
m_graphicsQueue = m_logicalDevice->getQueuePtr(indices.graphicsFamily, 0);



VkQueue queue2 = m_graphicsQueue->getHandle();
VkQueue queue = m_graphicsQ.getHandle();
assert(queue == queue2);
result = vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
```

`queue` and `queue2` are the same as expected, but this code again gives `result` = `VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST`. Whether I set `queue` or `queue2` first does not matter. If I remove the line:

```
VkQueue queue2 = m_graphicsQueue->getHandle();
```

(and the assert, of course), then `result == VK_SUCCESS`. so, the problem is with retrieving the `VkQueue` value from the `unique_ptr<Queue>`. Why is use of the `unique_ptr` causing this problem?

Comment: "Why is my code not working?" Is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Why the class in the first place? All it really does is provide a sane default init. Also there is no need to keep the Queue by pointer.

Comment: @Krythic is not in of itself. Desired behavior seems there (although implicit) — working `VkQueue` wrapper. Demonstrating code is there too.

Comment: @JimOrcheson Wait, so the assert is true? Should be no difference to Vulkan then. Do you have Validation Layers enabled?

Comment: Should you use std::move to transfer ownership of returned getQueuePtr() to rValue ?

Comment: @krOoze Thanks for asking. I thought I was, but it turns out that I had not turned on validation layers. Turning it on led to fixing a second error, but at this point, I am getting another validation message and an access violation in a call to vkQueueSubmit. That error is not there when validation layers are turned off. Oh well, something else to look into.

Comment: @ratchet freak - Because I have to get the simple stuff working before adding functionality.

Comment: @JimOrcheson Well, when it comes to Vulkan, there is no point discussing anything before Validation errors are clear... ;; Access violation more often then not is null object or already deleted object used. ;; Maybe close the question — seems it is not particulary answerable in the current state after all, until you settle the above mundane errors.

Comment: @krOoze Thanks for the help. I have been able to clear all of the Vulkan validation errors and have a working program with validation turned on. Now back to working on my Vulkan C++ library and modifying the program to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Once I turned on validation and cleaned up all of the reported errors, the program worked. It is interesting that a Vulkan validation problem shows up as something else entirely.

Comment: As suspected. ;; It is not particualry interesting. That's what "undefined behavior" means. And why you need Validation Layers. Actually lucky you got `VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST`. The driver might have pretended nothing happened and you would discover the error year from now.